# PYTHON RE Dont split UNICODE Chars into surrogate pairs while matching

Tags: python, regex, unicode, surrogate-pairs

who know, if it is possible to forbidden regex while macthing splitting code points into surrogate pairs.

See the following example:

How it is now:

```
$ te = u'\U0001f600\U0001f600'
$ flags1 = regex.findall(".", te, re.UNICODE)
$ flags1
>>> [u'\ud83d', u'\ude00', u'\ud83d', u'\ude00']
```

My wish:

```
$ te = u'\U0001f600\U0001f600'
$ flags1 = regex.findall(".", te, re.UNICODE)
$ flags1
>>> [u'\U0001f600', u'\U0001f600']
```

Why am i actually need it, because i want to iterate over unicode string and get each iteration next unicode character.

See example:

```
for char in  regex.findall(".", te, re.UNICODE):
   print char
```

Thx you in advance=)

Comment: Which version of Python? I suspect it works fine from Python 3.4 on. I just tested in Python 3.6 and yes, it works great.

Comment: Same, I'm seeing a list containing two strings, each equal to a single smiley face emoji.

Comment: no, im working with 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression that matches a surrogate pair or anything.  This will work in wide and narrow builds of Python 2, but isn't needed in a wide build since it doesn't use surrogate pairs.

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> te = u'A\u5200\U0001f600\U0001f601\u5100Z'
>>> print re.findall(ur'[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|.', te, re.UNICODE)
[u'A', u'\u5200', u'\U0001f600', u'\U0001f601', u'\u5100', u'Z']
```

This will still work in the latest Python 3, but also isn't needed because surrogate pairs are no longer used in Unicode strings (no wide or narrow build anymore):

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> te = u'A\u5200\U0001f600\U0001f601\u5100Z'
>>> print(re.findall(r'[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|.', te))
['A', '刀', '', '', '儀', 'Z']
```

Works without the surrogate match:

```
>>> print(re.findall(r'.', te))
['A', '刀', '', '', '儀', 'Z']
```

And then you can just iterate normally in Python 3:

```
>>> for c in te:
...     print(c)
...
A
刀


儀
Z
```

Note there is still an issue with *graphemes* (Unicode code point combinations that represent a single character.  Here's a bad case:

```
>>> s = '‍‍‍'
>>> for c in s:
...     print(c)
...     


‍


‍


‍
```

The `regex` 3rd party module can match graphemes:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = '‍‍‍'
>>> for c in regex.findall('\X',s):
...     print(c)
...     
‍‍‍
```

Comment: cool, thx u=) looks great. it there any possibility for python 2.7 to add graphemes support into the general pattern, which you gave at the beginning of your answer? ---> r'[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|.'

Comment: and unfortunately your examples with graphemes issue doesn't work for python 2.7-((

Comment: @Egor Graphemes are complicated and require knowledge of the latest Unicode standard. 2.7 is old and the regex library for it is out of date.