# get unicode graphemes as unsplitted item with python2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7, unicode, surrogate-pairs, grapheme

any idea, if it is possible with regex (python 2.7) to get uniq chars unspitted into surrogate pairs for unicode graphemes?

According [This Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889234/9607318) this is possible with python 3.x.
See here:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = '‍‍‍'
>>> for c in regex.findall('\X',s):
...     print(c)
...     
‍‍‍
```

but for python 2.7 it seems not to work. See example:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = '‍‍‍'
>>> for c in regex.findall('\X',s):
...     print(c)
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
...
```

Any ideas how to make this works for python 2.7?=))))

Thx u in advance!!!=)

Comment: I suspect that on a narrow build of Python (which it seems you are using), that only the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) is supported.  The latest `regex` says it supports Unicode 11.0, but it still splits surrogate characters.  It works fine for graphemes in the BMP, e.g. 
`u'a\u0302'` (decomposed `â`).  With Python 2 end-of-life in 2020, best to upgrade.

Comment: thx! yap, i, also thinking to make next step. but python3.x is slowly as python 2.7 and there are not so many third-party-packages as for python2.7. so actually quite important aspects, which stop me everytime, if i think to upgrade my python distribution.